# Add View Not Covering Full Screen

Tags: android, firebase, view, sinch

Attached Layout and Code Please help me to get my Remote video in full screen

Adding View to Layout Code

```
private fun addVideoViews() {
    if (mVideoViewsAdded || sinchServiceInterface == null) {
        return  //early
    }
    val vc = sinchServiceInterface!!.getVideoController()
    if (vc != null) {
        val localView = findViewById<View>(com.ayush.flow.R.id.localVideo) as RelativeLayout
        val remoteview = findViewById<View>(com.ayush.flow.R.id.remoteVideo) as RelativeLayout

        val lview = vc.localView
        val rview=vc.remoteView


        localView.addView(lview)
        remoteview.addView(rview)
        mVideoViewsAdded = true


        localView.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                //this toggles the front camera to rear camera and vice versa
                vc.toggleCaptureDevicePosition()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

[image: This is what i get I want full background covered with view]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Enable fullscreen mode.
See this link
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive

Comment: remoteview.setLayoutParams(
  new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
remoteview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);